# Remove or reduce material bounce

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cannot remove the bounce from a stack of multiple objects (using Unity 5.4.0).  Imagine a number of slabs of concrete, 1x1, and height of 0.1.  I'm dropping them flat one on top of the other.  The first two or three act normal, but after 8 or 10 each subsequent slab makes the entire stack bounce and sway as if it were a stack of mattresses.

Ground uses a mesh collider, and all the other objects are box colliders. All the colliders share the same Physic Material, with Bounciness=0 and Bounce Combine=minimum.

Project Settings --> Physics: default material is the same as above, Bounce Threshold = 0, and I've even reduced Gravity to -4.0.

The Rigidbody Mass doesn't seem to impact this issue; I've tried everything from 0.1 to 10000.

I can see some improvement by the changes I've made above, but still, the actual slabs themselves still have this illusive element of bounciness to them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, I think you can just make a new material and set the bounciness of it there. You could also try out the materials in the Sample Assets. Inside the Sample Assets, they have a bounciness option.

Comment: Well, I just created a new material, yet in the Inspector there is no bounciness option for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add your boucing material in your collider:
[image]

Comment: I've done that already - see my second paragraph - "All colliders share the same Physics Material".